# Update array in Extension Delegate

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, watchkit, watchos-2

I'm using `ExtensionDelegate` so I can access the `evnts` variable from my `InterfaceController` (and `ComplicationController` eventually).

I **need to refresh `evnts` in `ExtensionDelegate` when I get data from `WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo`**, but can't figure out quite how, any ideas?

*The reason being: `evnts` is empty because it gets called before `WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo` runs to actually get the data.*

(Any questions just let me know, and will post any extra code as needed!)

**`ExtensionDelegate`:**

```
class ExtensionDelegate: NSObject, WKExtensionDelegate {
    var evnts = [Evnt]()
}
```

**`InterfaceController`:**

```
func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo userInfo: [String : AnyObject]) {

    if let tColorValue = userInfo["TeamColor"] as? String, let matchValue = userInfo["Matchup"] as? String {

        let myDelegate = WKExtension.sharedExtension().delegate as! ExtensionDelegate
        var extEvnts = myDelegate.evnts

        receivedData.append(["TeamColor" : tColorValue , "Matchup" : matchValue])
        extEvnts.append(Evnt(dataDictionary: ["TeamColor" : tColorValue , "Matchup" : matchValue]))

        doTable()

    } else {
        print("tColorValue and matchValue are not same as dictionary value")
    }

}


func doTable() {

    let myDelegate = WKExtension.sharedExtension().delegate as! ExtensionDelegate
    let extEvnts = myDelegate.evnts

    self.rowTable.setNumberOfRows(extEvnts.count, withRowType: "rows")

    for (index, evt) in extEvnts.enumerate() {

        if let row = rowTable.rowControllerAtIndex(index) as? TableRowController {

            row.mLabel.setText(evt.eventMatch)
            row.cGroup.setBackgroundColor(colorWithHexString(evt.eventTColor)) 
        } else {
            print("nope")
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Is that working in Swift yet?  I know you could do static class, but that was all at the time I last checked.  Let me know what type of thing your thinking, thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry about the previous post, are you able to make it as a static variable?

Comment: Not that I can figure out how, but maybe?  If you have a second, and can post what you're thinking that would rock

Comment: before I write any suggestion, what is there other purpose of `let myDelegate = WKExtension.sharedExtension().delegate as! ExtensionDelegate` than getting the variable you need?

Comment: Nope no other reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just make your `evnts` in `ExtensionDelegate` to be a static variable

```
class ExtensionDelegate: NSObject, WKExtensionDelegate {
    static var evnts = [Evnt]()
}
```

And then you also need to make change:

```
func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo userInfo: [String : AnyObject]) {

    if let tColorValue = userInfo["TeamColor"] as? String, let matchValue = userInfo["Matchup"] as? String {

        receivedData.append(["TeamColor" : tColorValue , "Matchup" : matchValue])
        ExtensionDelegate.evnts.append(Evnt(dataDictionary: ["TeamColor" : tColorValue , "Matchup" : matchValue]))

        doTable()

    } else {
        print("tColorValue and matchValue are not same as dictionary value")
    }

}
```

And

```
func doTable() {

    let extEvnts = ExtensionDelegate.evnts

    self.rowTable.setNumberOfRows(extEvnts.count, withRowType: "rows")

    for (index, evt) in extEvnts.enumerate() {

        if let row = rowTable.rowControllerAtIndex(index) as? TableRowController {

            row.mLabel.setText(evt.eventMatch)
            row.cGroup.setBackgroundColor(colorWithHexString(evt.eventTColor)) 
        } else {
            print("nope")
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Follow up, when I try to call `let extEvnts = ExtensionDelegate.evnts` in my `ComplicationController`, there are no items in the `extEvnts` array.  Why would that be?

Comment: there are multiple things you can do for debugging: 1) set break point to see the value 2) print out the value when u append 3) go over the flow see if all the conditions are met 4) if there are any async call, u should manager ur code to adopt it

Comment: I set a break point and saw that the value was 0.  It seems to me like `extEvnts` is 0 because `WCSession` never gets called when the `ComplicationController` code is being run.  If I'm running the Simulator, when I run the Complication, the running of WatchKit app stops.  So I'm thinking that somehow the `ComplicationController` needs `ExtensionDelegate` to be loaded/refreshed by the `WCSession` data. Does that make sense?  Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: It is very hard to say......basically I have no idea about your application, you can consider open another question if you have some understanding about your issue :)